# いくら's meaning here

Tags: grammar

> これほどおいしい食べ物はいくら食べても食べ飽きない

What does いくら mean in this sentence?

I know it as "how much" but I can only guess what it means, which could be:

> No matter how much I eat delicious food like this, I will never grow tired of eating it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who/what/how much etc. + Verb in て-form + も = no matter who/what/how much ...

So いくら食べても is "no matter how much you eat", so I think your translation is spot on.

Comment: Ah thank you for the quick response. I'm really glad my translation was good. Thank you

Comment: @TylerH Do you think the answer fully explained your question? If so, consider ticking the check mark.